# how to deal with `&rest` args in common lisp

Tags: common-lisp

I am new to common lisp, when I see `&rest` in function arguments declaration, I thought it is similar to `*args` in `ruby`. And I started to write a function `sumit` to do the same thing as `+`.

```
(defun sumit (&rest args)
  (if (null args)
      0
      (+ (car args) (sumit (cdr args)))))
```

but when I invoke `(sumit 1 2 3)` it gets segmentation fault, the recursion never ends. `(sumit)` works though.

So my suspect is `(null args)` part, but after changing something like `(eql nil args)` or something similar does not work.

So what is the right way to decompose `&rest` args? What is the right way to check `nil`?

Comment: `SUMIT` takes a variable number of numbers as arguments, but in `(sumit (cdr args))` you're calling it with a single list argument, not numbers. You need to use `(apply #'sumit (cdr args))` instead.

Comment: @jkiiski ohhh, that's right! thx! btw, is there any way to expand list into multiple arguments without usage of `apply`?

Comment: @delta: no, use APPLY

Comment: Note also that supported argument list lengths can be as low as 50 in portable Common Lisp. Then no more than 50 arguments would be supported by an implementation. This means that you can't apply arbitrary number of arguments to functions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(sumit (cdr args))` calls `sumit` on a single argument - a list.
You need to use [`apply`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm):

```
(defun sumit (&rest args)
  (if args
      (+ (car args) (apply #'sumit (cdr args)))
      0))
```

Notes:

1. This implementation is not tail-recursive (while ANSI CL does *not* require tail call optimization, many implementations *do* provide it).
2. Take a look at [`call-arguments-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_call_a.htm)
   and [`lambda-parameters-limit`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/v_lamb_1.htm%60).
3. To sum elements of a list one can use `(apply #'+ list-of-numbers)`,
   but, due to the above two variables,
   [`(reduce #'+ list-of-numbers)`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_reduce.htm)
   is a far better approach.

Comment: Regarding note 1, Common Lisp doesn't guarantee tail recursion anyway.