# Common lisp: accept variable number of arguments and call another function using spread syntax

Tags: common-lisp

In many languages I have used, there is a way to have a variable number of arguments in the function signature, e.g. in Go you can declare a function with `func doSomething(args ...int)` and call it with `doSomething(2, 3, 4)` or in Python `def do_something(*args)` and `do_something(1, 2, 3)`, etc. Additionally, there is some syntax for spreading/unpacking these args, e.g. in Go `things = append(things, others...)` or in Python `do_something_else(*args)`.

I want to make a wrapper that takes a format string and passes it and any number of arguments to `format t`. Since `format` takes a variable number of arguments, my guess is that this is a language feature, yet I have not been able to find any explanation of how to do this.

The code I have that does not work correctly looks like this:

```lisp
(defun printf (fstr vals)
  (format t (concatenate 'string fstr "~%") vals))
```

If I call it with a format string that requires 1 value, it works fine, but I have no idea how to make it work with more than that. For example, `(printf "~d is not ~a" 12 "13")` results in the error "too many arguments given to printf". I also tried the following:

```lisp
(defun printf (fstr &rest vals)
  (format t (concatenate 'string fstr "~%") vals))
```

The error then says "there are not enough arguments left for this format directive". It is clear that `vals` is a list of arguments, but I have no idea how to expand them to pass to the call to `format t`.

Am I accepting args correctly by using the `&rest` notation? How do I expand that list of values in the call to `format t`?

Answer (score 5):

Your example

```
(defun printf (fstr &rest vals)
  (apply #'format t (concatenate 'string fstr "~%") vals))
```

`&rest` declares the `vals` parameter to take a list of the remaining arguments.

**Example of &rest and apply**

```
CL-USER 36 > (defun example (a b &rest c) (values a b c))
EXAMPLE

CL-USER 37 > (example 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
1
2
(3 4 5 6 7 8)
```

Above one can see that `c` is bound to the list `(3 4 5 6 7 8)`. `a` and `b` are bound to the arguments `1` and `2`.

`apply` calls a function with arguments taken from a list. The last argument of `apply` needs to be a list.

```
CL-USER 38 > (apply #'+ 1 2 '(3 4 5 6 7 8))
36
```

Now we can use `apply` in our `example` function:

```
CL-USER 39 > (defun example (a b &rest c)
               (apply #'+ a b c))
EXAMPLE

CL-USER 40 > (example 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8)
36
```

Comment: I read somewhere after posting this question that the single quote syntax passes something as a symbol rather than as a value, but I'm not sure what the hashtag does. Can you add a quick note about that specific syntax?

Comment: @JonathanVoss: it retrieves the function object.

Comment: @JonathanVoss -- `#'+` is an equivalent shorthand for [`(function +)`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/s_fn.htm).

Answer (score 1):

Found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2346004/2103394) after posting. (Did not know the keywords "unroll" or "splat" were relevant here.) The answer seems to be to use apply.

```lisp
(defun printf (fstr &rest vals)
  (apply #'format t (concatenate 'string fstr "~%") vals))
```

I do not understand how/why it works, but it does. Somehow, this is syntactically equivalent to the spread operators in JavaScript, Python, and Go.

Comment: unroll/splat were used by the person asking the question, but asking about how to call a function on a list of arguments or how to use `&rest` arguments is how the questions would have been fine too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42219300/how-to-deal-with-rest-args-in-common-lisp/42228285#42228285.

Comment: APPLY and FUNCALL are fundamental functions that you really have to understand if you wish to use Common Lisp. http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_apply.htm See also : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862394/when-do-you-use-apply-and-when-funcall